# R issue: "Object not found" MANOVA

Tags: r, object, manova

I'm an undergraduate and extremely new to R. I'm trying to run a MANOVA with 3 dependent variables and when I try to cbind my variables, the error "object not found" comes up.

I've tried finding how to direct it to read my column names as object, but I just can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read about [how to post a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can help you better.

Comment: please edit your question to show the codes that you used and the resulting error message

Comment: Please post a sample of your data and the code you are using